# git config --global core.autocrlf false still tries to convert line endings?

Tags: git

I have set:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Yet I still get warnings:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ...
```

I do not want Git to mess with my line endings at all, just **check the files in and out as they are**.

I'm on Windows 7. `git version 2.19.1.windows.1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Original EOL-change implementations (like autocrlf) are a mess. Try with the new implementation that uses attributes. Set this in `.git/info/attributes` (or in `.gitattributes` and add/commit it if you want to share it with other developers) to tell git to **not** mess with EOL on files (so it's all up to you and your text editors/IDEs):

```
* -text
```

Check `git help attributes` for more info.